# Facing Error When Linking A Library With React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-native

I've installed a library called [react-native-imei](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imei). After installing I've linked this library with React Native like `react-native link react-native-imei`. After it when I'm running the project so I'm facing errors. The errors are mentioned below.

```
> Task :react-native-imei:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :realm:forwardDebugPort
8083

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
329 actionable tasks: 22 executed, 307 up-to-date
Note: /home/zain/Desktop/Kolachi/demo/pos-proto/node_modules/react-native-imei/android/src/main/java/codes/simen/IMEI/RNImeiModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
/home/zain/Desktop/Kolachi/demo/pos-proto/android/app/src/main/java/com/resturantapp/MainApplication.java:82: error: incompatible types: MainReactPackage cannot be converted to int
      packages.add(new MainReactPackage(),
                   ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of react native you're using right now? In my case this package is running successfully.

Comment: "react-native": "0.60.5"

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-native>=60.0, then no need to use `react-native link react-native-imei`. It will be automatically linked.

Since this package reads phone's state you've to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` into `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` this file.

On devices before SDK version 23, the permissions are automatically granted if they appear in the manifest. Otherwise you have to follow this procedure.

`import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';`

```js
try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE,
    {
      title: "Phone State's Permission",
      message: "This app needs access to your phone's state",
      buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
      buttonNegative: "Cancel",
      buttonPositive: "OK"
    }
  );
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    console.log("You can read phone's state");

    IMEI.getImei().then(imeiList => {
      console.log("imeiList"); // prints ["AABBBBBBCCCCCCD"]
      console.log(imeiList); // prints ["AABBBBBBCCCCCCD"]
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Permission denied");
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: no it gives me error in android studio. I'm unable to build

Comment: Can you please share your `buildscript` section from `android/build.gradle` file?

Comment: Please change your `distributionUrl`  in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`  from `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip`.

Comment: After that, simply enter into your react-native project folder and run `./gradlew clean` from project's `android` directory.

Answer (score 0):

> /home/zain/Desktop/Kolachi/demo/pos-proto/android/app/src/main/java/com/resturantapp/MainApplication.java:82:
>   error: incompatible types: MainReactPackage cannot be converted to int
>         packages.add(new MainReactPackage(),

This is the error, Can you check why there is a MainReactPackage added in MainApplication.java in your android src/main.java/com/restaurantapp folder. In fact remove or comment out the below line and run the project again.

> `packages.add(new MainReactPackage(),`

You don't need to add the packages anymore. RN0.60 and above supports auto-linking. I commented out my packages because they are no longer needed.

Comment: After removing that line, my app is installed in my phone but I'm facing an another error which is `AppState is not available is this app`.